# How to detect invalid thread group setting in macOs metal GPU

Tags: apple-m1, metal

I was writing and testing macOS (M1) with metal gpu programming. I noticed if I accidently launch more threads than [1] `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup`, the metal program still can launch but the results are incorrect.

Is there a way to detect this error? (I checked the command buffer status, not helpful)

[1] https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/compute_passes/calculating_threadgroup_and_grid_sizes?language=objc

Comment: Don't launch more than `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup` threads? Detecting it after it happened won't really help you to fix the issue. You can try Metal Validation. You can either enable it in Xcode or by passing `MTL_DEBUG_LAYER=1` envrionment variable. Read `man MetalValidation` to learn more.